# Как узнать путь до файла из другого файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я узнаю путь до текущего каталога с помощью 
`currentDir = os.path.dirname(__file__)`.
Я сделал функцию которая возвращает значение currentDir, и импортировал ее в другой файл, и конечно мне выдало путь до каталога, из которого я импортирую. 
Как можно сделать функцию, которая при импортировании в другой файл, возвращала полный путь до этого, "другого", файла ?

Вопрос и описание немного не корректны мне нужно именно полный путь до каталога, и которого запускается файл.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример: два файла, в каких папках они лежат и какой путь в каком файле должен быть получен. И заодно код своей функции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого Вам нужно найти вызывающий код и его файл, то есть, анализировать стек вызова текущей функции. Как раз для этого существует встроенный модуль [**inspect**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html). Пример:

Файл `mytest.py`:

```py
import inspect

def task():
    # берём вызвавший эту функцию фрейм
    frm = inspect.stack()[1]
    # берём модуль Питона этого фрейма
    mod = inspect.getmodule(frm[0])
    # используем нужные переменные
    print(mod.__file__)
```

Файл `main.py`:

```py
from mytest import task
task()
```

Вывод:

> /Users/AivanF/Desktop/main.py